# How to find optimal penaltyparameter C for SVM (regression)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, python

I am training an svm regressor using python sklearn.svm.SVR

From the example given on the sklearn website, the above line of code defines my svm.

```
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
```

where C is "penalty parameter C of the error term."

My question is, how to find optimal value for C. Is there a method or some libraries which could help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: Questions about finding optimal values are fine here, but if you are asking for code or a library, that would be off-topic for CV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an RBF kernel as in the code example, you should be optimizing $C$ and $\gamma$ *together*. The most common way to optimize hyperparameters is through grid search, but this is not efficient.

Principled method to optimize hyperparameters are available in specialized libraries, such as [Optunity](http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (code example specifically for SVM [here](http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/python/sklearn/svc.html), disclaimer: I'm the lead dev of Optunity). Such libraries offer specialized black-box function optimizers that efficiently find good sets of hyperparameters. Alternatives include Hyperopt, SMAC and Spearmint.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing cross-validation to select the best C.

Comment: I am doing this currently, but feels a lot like guessing and takes a huge amount of time to run one cycle 5-fold cross validation.

Comment: Yeah, CV feels like guessing but C is a free parameter, its difficult to find a method to guess it a priori. If you want to speed up the computation a bit you can try to find a some "rule of thumb" for C and start the CV at that point

Comment: At present, this seems a bit more like a comment than an answer. Would you mind expanding it a little? How would you use cross-validation to select the best C?